# Strange behaviour when printing pointers

Tags: c, gcc

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int* arg1;
  int  arg2;
} data;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  data d;
  printf("arg1: %p | arg2: %d\n", d.arg1, d.arg2);
}
```

The output ends up being that `d.arg1` is not `NULL` and `d.arg2` is 0.  For example:

```
arg1: 0x7fff84b3d660 | arg2: 0
```

When I add a pointer to main, nothing changes.  However, when I print that pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int* arg1;
  int  arg2;
} data;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  data d;
  int* test;
  printf("arg1: %p | arg2: %d | test: %p\n", d.arg1, d.arg2, test);
}
```

the output always results in:

```
arg1: (nil) | arg2: 4195264 | test: (nil)
```

Why am I experiencing this behaviour?  I don't understand how printing another pointer value changes the value of a different pointer to NULL.  Note that the compiler I am using is GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: So the problem is just that my program experiences undefined behaviour?  Not necessarily the coincidence that adding a new variable changes things?

Comment: This is typical, no surprise: if you use uninitialized values, and you add another variable, that can change what values you see in the original, uninitialized values.

Comment: I don't think the difference is with you `printf`ing another pointer value, it is probably with you *allocating* another pointer on the stack.

Comment: init, *init*, **init**!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are experiencing this behavior because your program invokes **undefined behavior**. `d` is uinitialized in your program and hence its value is **indeterminate** and this invokes undefined behavior.

**C11 6.7.9 Initialization:**

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11241238/2455888):

> An *indeterminate value* even more unspecified than unspecified. It's either an unspecified value or a trap representation. A trap representation is standards-speak for some magic value which, if you try to assign it to anything, results in undefined behavior. This wouldn't have to be an actual value; probably the best way to think about it is "if C had exceptions, a trap representation would be an exception". For example, if you declare `int i;` in a block, without an initialization, the initial value of the variable `i` is indeterminate, meaning that if you try to assign this to something else before initializing it, the behavior is undefined, and the compiler is entitled to try the said demons-out-of-nose trick. Of course, in most cases, the compiler will do something less dramatic/fun, like initialize it to 0 or some other random valid value, but no matter what it does, you're not entitled to object.

Comment: reading an *indeterminate value* is not *UB* if the type does not have trap representations. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25793410

Comment: @Deduplicator; Yes. I stated this indirectly in the quoted para.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize d to get deterministic results:

```
data d = {0, 42};
```

or:

```
data d;
d.arg1 = 0;
d.arg2 = 42;
```

Without initialization, using the values leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing uninitialized values. This causes undefined behaviour (meaning that anything can happen, including the program crashing).

To fix, initialize values before using them, e.g.:

```
 data d = { 0 };
```

Answer (score 1):

d is uninitialized, so it can contain anything.