# Different outcomes when i initialize my variable

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int a = 0; 
    char letters[10] = {'a','B','c','D','e','F','g','H','i','J',};
    char c;
    while(letters[i])
        {
            c=letters[i];
            if(isupper(c))
                {
                    a+=1;
                }
            i++;
        }
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

just a simple program to count the amount of uppercase letters in an array

- when i set int a; i get a 4
- when i set int a = 0; i get a 6

i have zero idea why, please be nice as i know its probably something really stupid i can't see

Comment: `letters` is tot zero terminated, hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: ah, thank you i believe you are referring to \0 at the end of my array.

Comment: Correct, `\0` is missing. But you can perhaps do just `char letters[] = "aBcDeFgHiJ"` and get `\0` for free.

Comment: Please write standard English, including capitals.

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first post

Comment: @BrandonMoffatt You know, you can [edit] it to correct that.

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize your variables. Modifying a variable that was declared but never initialized is undefined behavior. The standard does not specify that variables must be default initialized just because they are declared.

```
int a;      // Value unknown / unspecified at runtime

int a = 0;  // Value is known to be 0
```

Also, this loop produces undefined behavior if it steps past the end of the allocated array.

```
while(letters[i])
{
     ...
     i++;
}
```

Comment: "Modifying a variable that was ..." Really? See [this plug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25793410). Regarding the loop: ... and it does. Additional point: A `char` may be `signed`, in which case it must be cast to `unsigned char` before passing to `isupper`. Not a problem in this case, as all ASCII-characters are < 128 anyway.