# Why does accessing elements from an uninitilized array output strange values?

Tags: c++, c

### Main Problem

I created array without initialization and used `printf()` function to access random element from it. Everytime I run my program I get strange values in the console.

```
float yearsAvg[5];
printf("%f\n", yearsAvg[4]); // it's outputing -nan in the console or some random values
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: The array is not initialized, so it can contain any valid or invalid number.

Comment: Enable **Compiler Warnings**, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on gcc/clang or `/W3` on VS (check options for other compilers -- all will have similar)

Comment: You have a program with [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240484/what-is-indeterminate-behavior-in-c-how-is-it-different-from-undefined-behav).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using uninitialized array will contain a garbage value and using them will produce some unexpected results for you. To fix it, just simply initialize it:

```
// Initializing each element of array with 0.0 value
float yearsAvg[5] = {0.0};
printf("%f\n", yearsAvg[4]);
```

See it live on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk8AO2kSD).

---

**Note:** To initialize `1.0` or something else to all elements, `{1.0}` will be no longer a valid syntax to achieve your desire. You have then two options here:

**1. When different values are to be assigned in different array elements:**

```
int my_array[3];
my_array[0] = 1;
my_array[1] = 5;
my_array[2] = 3;
```

**2. Or, they are required to be initialized with a common value except zero:**

```
int common_value = 50;
int my_array[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  my_array[i] = common_value;
```

Also, note that `{3.5}` - such type of initialization is valid in C++, i.e. you can assign such values including zeroes in this manner.

Comment: If I only specify one value as you did it here will it be assigned to the all elements in the array? What if I only want to initalize the value for the first element?

Comment: @bartekw2213 simply use `yearsAvg[0] = 0.0` on the next line and remove `= {0.0}`. See [live](https://onlinegdb.com/SkWn9Yh1BD).

Comment: @bartekw2213 If you initialize any part of the array then it initializes the whole array - that's just how the language works.

Comment: Keep in mind that the remainder of the array is initialized with 0s. So `float yearsAvg[5] = {1};` for example will give you an array containing `{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: @Kevin yes. But this is valid in case of C++ since that supports such initialization.

Comment: @RohanBari I didn't say otherwise. But your answer doesn't make it clear that the value given will only be assigned to the first element.

Comment: @Kevin I have updated the answer. Check it out, maybe it clears the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

An array is a pointer to a series of memory addresses assigned.

```
float yearsAvg[5];
```

Assigned 5*(sizeof(float)) [i.e. 5*4=20 Bytes] with `yearsAvg` pointer pointing to the first element. Now the memory initially contains garbage (random) value or in your case `NULL` being represented by `-nan` in console.

You can do the following to initialise all values as zero when you declare the array.

```
float yearsAvg[5] =  { };             // yearsAvg = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
int yearsAvg[5] =  { 0 };             // yearsAvg = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```