# How could I bring this code that is in C ++ to C? ... it is important :(

Tags: c

The code is the following, I have doubts in the line that is inside the for, I do not know how to bring it to the C language, only that line, the rest I know, it is the NRU paging algorithm.

```
int numberofframes;
int references;
char *pages;
char *faults;
char **frametable;
        
cout << "\nEnter the number of references of pages you want to have: ";
cin >> references;
pages = new char[references];
faults = new char[references];
        
//The matrix for the frames is created
frametable= new char*[numberofframes];
for(i = 0; i < amountofframes; i++){
   frametable[i] = new char[references];//What would this line in C look like?
}
```

Comment: [Reading a text file into a 2D Dynamic Array using double pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052062/3422102) from earlier tonight may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocation in C is usually done with `malloc`.

```
frametable[i] = malloc(references * sizeof *frametable);
```

Alternatively, you could use `calloc`:

```
frametable[i] = calloc(references, sizeof *frametable);
```

As you can see, the important part is determining the size of the memory allocation, and ideally you would use `sizeof` of the variable you want to put it into. In this case, `frametable` is of type `char **` or a "pointer to pointers" an "array of pointers". The `sizeof *frametable` is used to determine the size of such a pointer.

Comment: Should be `frametable[i] = malloc(references * sizeof *frametable[i]);` or `frametable[i] = malloc(references * sizeof **frametable);` (you always use the size of the dereferenced pointer, in this case the pointer is `frametable[i]`) Given type `char` simply `frametable[i] = malloc(references);` would do.

Comment: If that is unclear, the current allocation you show over-allocates by a factor of `sizeof(a_pointer)`. Since `frametable[i]` is type `char*` you want to allocate characters, not pointers.