# Pointer on the stack returns correct value to the outside in C

Tags: c

I have read about the evil of returning addresses of stack-based variables, but I am confused with the following case. In the function f I am returning the pointer p which holds the address of i, both of which are local variables. I expected to get some undefined behavior when I call the f function, but the call in the main function returns correctly the value of the local i namely 14. Is this just an accident and itself an undefined behavior, or why am I able to return that address to the outside world of the function?

```c
#include <stdio.h>



char *f()
{
  char *p;
  char  i =14;
  p=&i;
  return p;
}


int main()
{
  
  printf("%d", *f());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior even if it "happens to work".

Comment: A function can always return it own type. `f()` can return `char *`. `p` holds the address of `i`. When the function returns, the address for `i` in `p` is returned, but memory holding the function stack is destroyed (released for re-use) leaving the address for `i` held by `p` invalid -- resulting in *Undefined Behavior*... Bad Juju...

Comment: See: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/3422102) and [What is indeterminate behavior in C++ ? How is it different from undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11240484/3422102) and [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)

Comment: Why do you assume that the variable `i` actually ends up on the stack after compilation? Check: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: `"why am I able to return that address to the outside world of the function?"` -- See [this answer to a similar C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/12149471) for a nice explanation in the form of an analogy.

Answer (score 4):

It is still undefined behavior and it just happens to work here.

The value of `i` is still on the stack because nothing has overwritten it yet

If you were to run it on a different architecture, or with different compiler settings it might not work.

If you were to do something like this, It no longer returns the correct value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *f()
{
  char *p;
  char  i =14;
  p=&i;
  return p;
}

void g()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 3;
    printf("%d",a+b);
}


int main()
{
  char* c = f();
  g();
  printf("%s", c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe even more fun, simply `void g(int a, int b) { printf("%d",a+b); }` and in `main()` have `int a = 1, b = 3;` and call `g (a, b)`.  Roughly the same.

Comment: @Samuel What is the implication of the function g here? Is it taking over the place of *c on the `main` stack?

Comment: @Student `g()` is just a function that does something, it doesn't matter what. When you call another function it uses the same area on the stack as the previous function call to store it's variables. Depending on the compiler you may also get this behavior if you declare more variables after the call to `f()`.

Comment: Every function call uses memory -- to provide stack space for the function (e.g. the function stack). So in some implementations, `g()` will re-use the memory released on `f()` return causing the memory address returned by `f()` to be overwritten corrupting what was `i`.

Answer (score 3):

If undefined behavior was guaranteed to give you wrong results, C programming would be so much easier.

Instead, you get weird behavior like this, where enabling basic optimizations breaks your program (Debian gcc 10.2.0-16):

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo && ./foo
14
$ gcc -O foo.c -o foo && ./foo
0
```

Now your program will probably crash in prod, and any attempt to step through it in a debugger in dev will not show the problem.