# Strncat returns garbage values

Tags: c

I am learning GLFW and I am making a code to load shaders into my code. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char* loadShader(const char* shaderName){
    FILE *shader = fopen(shaderName, "r");
    char c;
    char* realShader;
    while ((c = fgetc(shader))!= EOF){
        strncat(realShader, &c, sizeof(c));
    }
    return realShader;
}


int main(void){
    char* filename = "default";
    char* shader = loadShader(filename);
    printf("%s\n", shader);
    return 0;
}
```

I tested this with the following text file(i.e. default):

```
hello world
bye world
```

But this returns `P a hello world aaa`

Then I used another test file (default.frag):

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main(){
    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

and this returns

```
P a#version 330 a
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `char* realShader;` Where does that point? You need to allocate some memory into which you concatenate your source string(s). And you need to read up on how `strncat` works - it take **nul-terminated strings** as input, not single characters.

Comment: Reading a file character by character is needlessly complicated, a simpler solution can be found in e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174531/how-to-read-the-content-of-a-file-to-a-string-in-c

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Mole. I tried char* realShader = malloc(sizeof(shader)); and it worked

Comment: That only works by sheer accident.

Comment: See: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/3422102) and [What is indeterminate behavior in C++ ? How is it different from undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11240484/3422102) and [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)

Comment: Functions like `strncat`, `strncpy`, `snprintf` etc. almost always need a `size_t` argument indicating the amount of space remaining in the *destination* buffer. If you are relating it *not* to the destination buffer and *only* to the source buffer, this should be a good indication you might be doing something wrong. It is only when there's some kind of guarantee about the destination buffer size that the `n` functions can realistically safely "ignore" it.

Answer (score 2):

`strncat` was made for *strings*. But `&c` is not a string.

Also, the original buffer is never allocated, so its contents is undefined. You're lucky that the program didn't immediately crash.

Afer allocating a suitable buffer, you could use `fgets` here, or keep reading the characters in, one by one. In this latter case, remember to add a terminating zero, as this is the C standard for strings. If you use `fgets`, you'll read in also any line-terminating character ("\n"), and you might want to remove it.

Also, remember to **close** the files when you're through using them, or before exiting the function where the file pointer is defined - otherwise, system resources will leak.

For example:

```
FILE *shader;
char* realShader;

// Open the file, and check that opening succeeded.
if (NULL != (shader = fopen(shaderName, "r"))) {
    // Allocate some memory for realShader, and check
    // that the allocation did work.
    if (NULL != (realShader = malloc(1024))) {
        char *c;
        // Read one line
        if (NULL == fgets(realShader, 1024, shader)) {
            // Read failed. No sense in keeping memory allocated
            free(realShader); realShader = NULL;
        } else {
            // If there is a return at end of line...
            c = strchr(realShader, '\n');
            if (c) {
                // ...kill it.
                *c = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(shader); // shader = NULL;
}
return realShader;
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to read the **whole** file, then you need to know its size (unless you want to use `realloc` in a cycle, also doable). For that, you would use the `stat` function after temporarily allocating a buffer for the stat info:

```
// Create the structure on the stack as a temporary variable
// (no malloc)
struct stat statbuf;
fstat(shaderName, &statbuf);

// This is, in general, not a good idea because "st_size" is not
// necessarily what malloc expects. On my system it is a 64 bit
// value, and so is malloc's size_t, so things work. Otherwise a
// compiler warning is the least you can expect.
// (also, blindly loading large chunks of data into memory is
// not the first thing you should go for if at all avoidable).
realShader = malloc(statbuf.st_size);
```

Comment: @AdrianMole good point (edited answer).

Comment: Thank-you - I 'edited' my vote! :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole you were right in objecting to 'vague terms', but the thing is,  I often find that if I just plug in some working code, there's a risk it will be blindly adopted - and maybe I did not consider all edge cases, or misunderstood, or it works in the scenario I thought but not in the real one. So I often prefer to "encourage" to read the manuals and understand what the code *does*.

Comment: Not a problem. I've been in similar situations ... it's sometimes a tricky call with 'homework' style questions. But, ultimately, we want good, complete answers on Stack Overflow, which stand the test of time.