# Undefined reference to constructor problem

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, constructor

See the below-given code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number
{
    int a;

public:
    Number();

    Number(int num_1) {
        a = num_1;
    }

    void print_number(void) { cout << "Value of a is " << a << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Number num_1(33), num_3;
    Number num_2(num_1);

    num_2.print_number();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I am having 2 constructors in the same class but when compiling it,gives me the error

```
ccnd0o9C.o:xx.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `Number::Number()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone solve this problem? and I still need the 2 constructors but without replacing `num_3`  with `num_3()` the main function.

Comment: TYPO: change `Number(void);` to `Number(){}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your class, you have declared the default constructor, but you have not defined it.

You can [`default` it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) (since C++11) and you will be good to go:

```
Number() = default;
```

Otherwise:

```
Number() {}
```

As from @TedLyngmo liked post, both will behave the same, but the class will get different meaning as per the standard, though. More reads here:
[The new syntax "= default" in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828907/the-new-syntax-default-in-c11/20828970#20828970)

---

@Jarod42's Comment as side notes: The default constructor make sense when it provide a default value to the member `a`. Otherwise it will be uninitialized (indeterminate value) and [reading them will cause to UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240484/what-is-indeterminate-behavior-in-c-how-is-it-different-from-undefined-behav).

Comment: This is the preferable way to do it. See [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20828970/7582247)

Comment: Notice that `= default;` or `{}` is risky here, as `a` would not be initialized, and so `num_3.print_number();` would lead to UB.

Comment: `Number(int num_1 = 0)` might make sense as alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Number
{
    int a;

public:
    Number(){};
    Number(int num_1)
    {
        a = num_1;
    }

    void print_number(void) { cout << "Value of a is " << a << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Number num_1(33), num_3;

    Number num_2(num_1);
    num_2.print_number();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you explained WHY this code is needed.

Comment: People who don't know what's wrong in OPs code will find it hard to spot the change you have made. Answers should be more about explaining problems and solutions than about providing ready-to-use code.

Comment: Notice that `{}` (or even  `= default;`) is risky here, as `a` would not be initialized, and so `num_3.print_number();` would lead to UB.