# The output is weird on my C Console App. Any ideas?

Tags: c

I want to make an app that determines whether the given input is a positive number, and then prints them out if there are more than 2 positive numbers, but there is a weird output which I've been trying to fix for a few hours.
Note : I'm somewhat of a beginner in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char arr[][20] = {"First Number : ", "Second Number : ", "Third Number : "};
    int numbers[2]; // number list
    int posNumbers[2]; // positive number list
    int n = 0; // n for itinerating posNUmbers

    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 2; i++) {
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
        scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);
    } // puts input in array

    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]) + 1 ; i++ ) {
        if (numbers[i] > 0) {
            posNumbers[n + 1] = numbers[i];
        }
    } // adds positive in array

    if (sizeof(posNumbers) / sizeof(posNumbers[0]) + 1 > 1) {
        printf("There are atleast 2 pos numbers, which are : \n");
        for ( int i = 0; i <= sizeof(posNumbers) / sizeof(posNumbers[0]) + 1 ; i++) {
           printf("%i", posNumbers[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("THere are not enough positive numbers.");
    }
}
```

Output : `There are atleast 2 pos numbers, which are :  4419368778941968054388`

Comment: `&numbers[2]` breaks the array bounds.

Comment: And `i <= sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]) + 1` is off by two. Your loops should be `i < sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0])`

Comment: And `if (sizeof(posNumbers) / sizeof(posNumbers[0]) + 1 > 1)` is always `true`.

Comment: In C arrays are **zero** based. Valid indexes are `0 <= index < size`. In the case of a character array that will be used as a C-string, there must also be room for the `'\0'` (nul-terminating character) following the last character in the string. In the case a C-string, the max number of characters that can be stored in an array of `size` is `0 <= index < size - 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several misconceptions about arrays and the use of `sizeof` that cause you to attempt to access values beyond the end of your `numbers` and `posNumbers` arrays that invokes *Undefined Behavior*<sup>1</sup> in your code. You further invoke *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to read from uninitialized elements in the `posNumbers` array.

In C, arrays are:

- **zero** based. Meaning that an array of `nelem` elements has valid indexes of `0 <= index < nelem`,
- when looping over all elements in an array, you loop from `i = 0; i < nelem; i++`,
- if you fail to initialize your arrays all zero and do not fill all elements and attempt to loop over all elements in your array, you invoke *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to access the uninitialized element (lesson -- initialize all arrays to begin with),
- when you use `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`, you get the total number of elements in the array, not the number of elements filled,
- your loop over `posNumbers` ignores the fact that less than all elements can be filled invoking *Undefined Behavior* if you attempt to read from an uninitialized element of the array,
- when filling less than all values in an array, simply keep a counter to track the number of elements filled, you have `n` declared already.

Additional points to consider:

- avoid using *MagicNumbers* in your code and instead `#define` a constant. This helps avoid the problems you are having with `2`,
- above all learn you cannot use `scanf()` (or any user input function) correctly unless you ***check the return***, especially where numeric conversions are involved. What if the user enters `"four"` instead of `4`?

Putting it altogether, and making a few additional changes to your output calls, you can rewrite your code to avoid the problems above as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define NVALS 3   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    /* an array of pointers to the string-literals is fine */
    const char *arr[] = { "First Number  : ", 
                          "Second Number : ", 
                          "Third Number  : " };
    int numbers[NVALS] = {0},       /* initialize all arrays */
        posNumbers[NVALS] = {0},
        n = 0;

    /* loop NVALS times reading number input */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NVALS; i++) {
        
        /* no conversion involved, fputs is fine for end-of-line control */
        fputs (arr[i], stdout);
        
        /* you can't use scanf correctly unless you CHECK THE RETURN
         * to validate each conversion was successfully completed
         */
        if (scanf("%i", &numbers[i]) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        
        /* compare if numbers[i] positive */
        if (numbers[i] > 0) {
            posNumbers[n++] = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    if (n > 1) {  /* check if at least two numbers positive */
        puts ("\nThere are atleast 2 pos numbers, which are :");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           printf ("%i\n", posNumbers[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        puts ("\nMust have at least two positive numbers.");
    }
}
```

(**note:** a good compiler will convert `printf ("const string");` to `fputs ("const string", stdout);` for you, but choosing `fputs()` over the variadic `printf()` when there are no conversions involved indicates you understand how to choose the proper tool for the job on your own)

**Example Use/Output**

If less than two positive integers:

```
$ ./bin/threeposnumbers
First Number  : -10
Second Number : 0
Third Number  : 4

Must have at least two positive numbers.
```

If the two positive numbers are provided:

```
$ /bin/threeposnumbers
First Number  : -10
Second Number : 2
Third Number  : 4

There are atleast 2 pos numbers, which are :
2
4
```

If all positive numbers are provided:

```
$ ./bin/threeposnumbers
First Number  : 10
Second Number : 2
Third Number  : 4

There are atleast 2 pos numbers, which are :
10
2
4
```

(if you are old enough, you will recall the special significance of those numbers for a specific soft-drink marketing campaign, hint: initials DP `:)`

Handling non-integer input:

```
$ ./bin/threeposnumbers
First Number  : -10
Second Number : two
error: invalid integer input.
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

---

**footnotes:**

**1.)** See:

- [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/3422102) and
- [What is indeterminate behavior in C++ ? How is it different from undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11240484/3422102) and
- [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to store 3 numbers but you are declaring your array size to be 2. If you want to store 3 numbers this code:

```
int numbers[2]; // number list
int posNumbers[2]; // positive number list
```

Should be

```
int numbers[3]; // number list
int posNumbers[3]; // positive number list
```

You are supposed to declare the array sizes as how big as you want them but you can only use up to `size - 1` since indexes start from 0.

Also you should probably fix the things that @WeatherVane is stating in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum on the answers: you can interleave then in a `struct` to make it clearer which variables go together. This can also reduce the number of times you repeat yourself.

You have: a) a fixed number of numbers to enter, and b) you are going to copy all the positive numbers to a second, possibly smaller, array. The simplest is to make an equal-size array and explicitly have the size. I would refactor the code as such,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct {
        const char *title;
        int number;
    } arr[] = { { "First", 0 }, { "Second", 0 }, { "Third", 0 } };
    struct {
        size_t size;
        int number[sizeof arr / sizeof *arr];
    } positives;
    const int arr_size = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];

    // enter numbers
    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < arr_size; i++) {
        printf("%s Number : ", arr[i].title);
        if(scanf("%i", &arr[i].number) != 1) return 1;
    }

    // adds positive in array
    positives.size = 0;
    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < arr_size ; i++ ) {
        if (arr[i].number > 0) {
            // bounded by arr_size
            positives.number[positives.size++] = arr[i].number;
        }
    }

    if (positives.size >= 2) {
        printf("There are atleast 2 pos numbers, which are : \n");
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < positives.size ; i++) {
           printf("%i\n", positives.number[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("THere are not enough positive numbers.\n");
    }
}
```